# Efficient Opensource to Debug CGI binaries in Unix

Tags: cgi

We have our code and binaries in Unix box .Few of the binaries are for web packages loaded by CGI .I use gdb in remote debugging mode to debug normal binaries but web binaries are difficult to debug because the process id changes every time the binary is loaded and gdb detaches .I heard in Visual studio there is a option to add in task manager and debug it .But i m afraid if i install Visual studio my system would go slow.Any suggestion on any other opensource tools available for efficient remote debugging of web binaries

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is to efactor the code so you can test most parts of it outside a CGI context with some unit testing system or something similar.

The second step would be to replay the CGI communication manually. It's not complicated - set the environment variables needed and eventuelly pipe the POST data in while running under gdb.

If that doesen't help you have to debug the web server and ask your debugger to follow child processes. Best thing is to start the httpd using the `-X` option so it runs with a single process itself. Then attach gdb and set the `set follow-fork-mode child` command. See gdb manual at http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html